# R cumulative sum using dplyr with reset

Tags: r, dplyr, cumsum

I am trying to make a table that counts the number of consecutive years grouped by columns "state" and "p" that looks like this:

```
    data_right <- data.table(state = c("NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY","NY", "PA", 
    "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA"), p = c("n", "n","n","n", "p", "p", "n", "n", "n", 
    "p", "p", "p"),Year = c("1973", "1974", "1977", "1978", "1988", "1989" ,"1991", 
    "1992", "1993", "1920", "1929", "1931"), Consecutive_Yrs = 
    c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,1))
```

The code I am using right now is not working properly. I'm trying mutate, and group_by statements in dplyr but am having no luck. I also cannot use the data.table package because my `R version` is not up to date.

Any help to get this output is greatly appreciated!

Comment: *"not working properly"*: it would help immensely to show what you have tried and why it is not working. Answers that are tuned more closely to your current coding style (or correcting bad practices within it) will ultimately help you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
data_right %>%
  group_by(state, p) %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(as.integer(Year)) > 1))) %>%
  group_by(state, p, grp) %>%
  mutate(cy = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-grp)
# # A tibble: 12 x 5
#    state p     Year  Consecutive_Yrs    cy
#    <chr> <chr> <chr>           <dbl> <int>
#  1 NY    n     1973                1     1
#  2 NY    n     1974                2     2
#  3 NY    n     1977                1     1
#  4 NY    n     1978                2     2
#  5 NY    p     1988                1     1
#  6 NY    p     1989                2     2
#  7 PA    n     1991                1     1
#  8 PA    n     1992                2     2
#  9 PA    n     1993                3     3
# 10 PA    p     1920                1     1
# 11 PA    p     1929                1     1
# 12 PA    p     1931                1     1
```

Assumes the data is already ordered by `Year`.

---

Data:

```r
data_right <- data.table(state = c("NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY","NY", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA", "PA"), p = c("n", "n","n","n", "p", "p", "n", "n", "n", "p", "p", "p"),Year = c("1973", "1974", "1977", "1978", "1988", "1989" ,"1991", "1992", "1993", "1920", "1929", "1931"), Consecutive_Yrs = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,1))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for situations when the data is structured like this: data_right <- data.table(state = c("NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY","NY", "PA", "PA", "PA", 
                                   "PA", "PA", "PA"), p = c("n", "n","n","n", "p", "p", "n", "n", "n", "p", "p", 
                                                            "p"),Year = c("1973", "1974", "1977", "1978", "1988", "1989" ,"1991", "1992", "1993", 
                                                                          "1920", "1929", "1931"), Consecutive_Yrs = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,1))

Comment: Your code outputs something like this: 
data_wrong <- data.table(state = c("NY", "NY", "NY", "NY", "NY","NY", "PA", "PA", "PA", 
                                   "PA", "PA", "PA"), p = c("n", "n","n","n", "p", "p", "n", "n", "n", "p", "p", 
                                                            "p"),Year = c("1973", "1974", "1977", "1978", "1988", "1989" ,"1991", "1992", "1993", 
                                                                          "1920", "1929", "1931"), Consecutive_Yrs = c(1,2,2,3,1,2,1,2,3,1,1,1))

Comment: Perhaps that's a better sample, then, to include in your question.

Comment: Ok I changed it in my question. I apologize, I didn't consider a case like that.